# regex - check date formats

Tags: php, regex, date

I'd like some help please. I'm having am input field where I'd like to check if the user has entered his date of birth in these formats: `dd/mm/yyyy` or `dd-mm-yyyy`

```
if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$/', $_POST['dob'])){
    // ok
} else {
    // there's an error
}
```

How can I change my regular expression to match either the `'/'` or `'-'` between the numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the patterns which matches date formats inside  a non-capturing group delimited by an alternation operator.

```
if(preg_match('~^[0-9]{2}(?:-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}|/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})$~', $_POST['dob'])){
    // ok
} else {
    // there's an error
}
```

**OR**

Use capturing group and then refer the capturing characters through back-referencing.

```
if(preg_match('~^[0-9]{2}([-/])[0-9]{2}\1[0-9]{4}$~', $_POST['dob'])){
    // ok
} else {
    // there's an error
}
```

[DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/zB3hI5/21)

[DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/zB3hI5/22)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! One more question if possible. How can I also split the date, either by / or - to an array? I'm using $dob = preg_split('//|- /', $dob)

Comment: `preg_split('~[/-]~', $dob)`